# Нужна ли запятая: "мелкая(,) кропотливая работа"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

Нужна ли запятая: "мелкая(,) кропотливая работа"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Мелкая(?) копотливая** работа…*

Смотрим в словарь: **Кропотливый**, 1. Требующий много внимания, усилий, терпения. К-ая работа.

Тогда нужно так:  ***Мелкая, кропотливая** работа.*

Почти синонимы, значения слов сближенные. Мелкая работа практически всегда кропотливая. Это однородные определения, запятая ставится.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое !

Comment: Спасибо за вопрос. В этой теме  не все просто, так как  для каждого варианта приходится подбирать свое решение.